# Why is this copy/paste in vim configuration not working properly?

Tags: linux, vim, osx, vimrc

I have the following in my `.vimrc`

```
vmap <C-c> y  
imap <C-p> <esc>P
```

So that I can do my classic sortcut for copy/paste.  It works fine on Cygwin but not in my `ssh` session to remote linux using a `Mac` client.

When I press `C-c` I see `X lines yanked` but when I press `C-p` only the first letter of the first line is pasted.

What is the problem?

Comment: Why in `Cygwin` there is no issue? Also what is the `+` for?

Comment: What version of vim are you using in cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

The -t option

```
 ssh -t
```

should fix your problem. [Here](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html) you have a detailed explanation of what happens when working over ssh.